# Ignore mailer layout for specific mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, mailer

The mailer layout in layouts/mailer.text.erb & layouts/mailer.html.erb currently shows up in all the mailer views I create. How can I exclude the mailer layout for two views (sent.text.erb & sent.html.erb)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [layout](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout) method. Adding something like `layout: 'mailer', except: :sent` to your mailer class should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

`layout 'your_layout', except: [:view_one, :view_two]`

The same can be done with `only:`

You can also specify a different layout in each action like this:

```
def your_action
  render layout: 'some_layout'
end
```

Comment: There is no controller for the mailer views I am trying to remove the layout from.